# Kurtosis interpretation

Tags: statistics, eda

For a set of data points I have found mean value is 2989.05,skewness is 26.67 and kurtosis is 1003.29.

Here it seems kurtosis is very high which I am not able to understand what it means.Can someone explain this.

Answer (score 1):

Moors' interpretation of kurtosis:  kurtosis is a measure of the dispersion of X around the two values μ ± σ.(mean ± S.D)

High values of kurtosis arise in two circumstances:

1) Highly densed at the tails of the distribution.
2) Your data points are concentrated around the mean, but because of presence of few outliers the kurtosis value become high

Answer (score 0):

It means you have an outlier problem. Kurtosis tells you nothing about the peak - negative kurtosis does not mean "low and broad" because the peak can be infinite with negative kurtosis. Also, the peak can be flat with infinite kurtosis, so large kurtosis does not tell you that you have a "high and sharp" peak.

You have a serious outlier situaiton. Have  look at your maximum value(s).